# Unable to save the data while using the extended Jouranl Component in AEM Communities

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have followed every step given in the following repo [GitHub - Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-scf-sample-components-extension: Sample package for AEM Social Communities - Social](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-scf-sample-components-extension)

I have added the subtitle property to "com.adobe.cq.social.journal.client.endpoints.impl.JournalOperationsService" and created a page using the given template and tried to add the extended journal component and clicked on New Article and tried to enter some content and clicked on publish immediately. But after I click on Publish it's taking me to the same page and no content is being published. And  I checked if the UGC is stored under /content/usergenerated/asi/jcr/content but no content is stored for the ectended Journal component.

Where as the other extended community components that are given in the above repo are  are working fine. I have added the required client libraries. Can anyone help me what am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I understood that when you are publishing a new blog article JS is not getting loaded.
Steps to resolve the issue:
1) Navigate to /etc/designs/acme/clientlibs/site 
2) Delete the JS folder and js.txt
That's it you are good to go.